# ASP.NET MVC Null Calculated Field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following calculated field in Vendor.cs:

```
public string FullAddress
    {
        get
        { 
            return VendorAddNum + " " + TLRoadDirection.Direction + " " + VendorAddName + " " + TLRoadType.RdType + " " + TLUnitTypeOne.UnitType + " " + VendorAddUnitOne + " " + TLUnitTypeTwo.UnitType + " " + VendorAddUnitTwo;
        }
    }
```

Here's the markup from the view for the field:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullAddress)
```

When one of my vendors doesn't have any address information, FullAddress is null, which causes me to get a null reference exception.  How can I allow FullAddress to be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of concatenating all of the values, use string interpolation to better handle `null` values:

```
return $"{VendorAddNum} {TLRoadDirection.Direction} {VendorAddName} {TLRoadType.RdType} {TLUnitTypeOne.UnitType} {VendorAddUnitOne} {TLUnitTypeTwo.UnitType} {VendorAddUnitTwo}";
```

As an added bonus, the performance is a little better and the code is a little cleaner.

---

If you're using an older version of C#, you can use `string.Format` similarly:

```
return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}", VendorAddNum, TLRoadDirection.Direction, VendorAddName, TLRoadType.RdType, TLUnitTypeOne.UnitType, VendorAddUnitOne, TLUnitTypeTwo.UnitType, VendorAddUnitTwo);
```

Comment: Well I thought this was the solution, but I didn't notice that I had a value (typo) in the VendorAddNum field.  When I remove that value, and all of the fields are null, I get the null reference exception again.  Any idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: @user1916528: Where are you getting the exception?  This code returns a string, not null.

Comment: When I attempt to go to the Index view I'm set back to the Vendor.cs file in VisualStudio.  The null reference exception is on this calculated field in the model.

Comment: @user1916528: It doesn’t sound like this property is *returning* null, but that it’s relying on something *else* that’s null.  There are 4 references to other properties (all starting with “TL”), one or more of them is likely null.

Comment: that was it, they were all causing the issue.  So it looks like I have a different issue to solve.  But your initial response was a terrific help and is the solution to my original question.